# Angular2 ng2-popover hide() is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular2-routing, ng2-bootstrap

app.module.ts

```
import { PopoverModule } from 'ng2-popover';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ...],
  imports: [PopoverModule],
  providers: []
})
```

example.html

```
<a [popover]="customPopover" [popoverOnHover]="true" [popoverCloseOnMouseOutside]="true" href="www.google.com" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" target="_blank">{{name}}</a>
    <!--Popover content -->
    <popover-content #customPopover title="{{name}}" placement="right" 
      [closeOnClickOutside]="true" [closeOnMouseOutside]="true">
      <span class="popoverDesc">{{description}}</span><br /><br />
      <a href="{{websiteLink | formatUrl:'url'}}" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" target="_blank">{{websiteLink | formatUrl:'text'}}</a><br /><br />
      <button class="btn btn-secondary popoverBtn" (click)="toggleAddToListModalPopover($event)">Add to list</button>
     </popover-content>
```

example.component.ts

```
import { PopoverContent } from 'ng2-popover';

@ViewChild('customPopover') customPopover: PopoverContent;

protected toggleAddToListModalPopover(e):void {
  this.customPopover.hide();
  this.showAddToListModal = !this.showAddToListModal;
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I want hide the popover when modal opens. When I call the 'customPopover.hide()' function it gives me error:

error_handler.js:51 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined

at PopoverContent.hide (PopoverContent.js:78)

In 'PopoverContent.js' file there is line this.popover.hide(); but I have no idea how to initialize it. As my understanding is @ViewChild only initializes the class bind to #customPopover i.e. in my case popover-content. Can someone please give me a solution to initialize the 'Popover'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your case, `this.customPopover` is undefined.

Other way you can hide your popover-content like this-

```
  <div>
    <popover-content #myPopover title="this header can be omitted" placement="right" [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
      <b>Very</b> <span style="color: #C21F39">Dynamic</span> <span style="color: #00b3ee">Reusable</span>
      <b><i><span style="color: #ffc520">Popover With</span></i></b> <small>Html support</small>. Click outside of this popover and it will be dismissed automatically.

      <u (click)="myPopover.hide()">Or click here to close it</u>.
    </popover-content>

    <button [popover]="myPopover">click this button to see a popover</button>
  </div>
```

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Sanket for giving a clue. Yes `this.customPopover` undefined. I resolved it using below code.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it using below code i.e. add 'customPopover' as parameter in the function and call hide() method. I don't know if its a good way to resolve this or not?

example.html

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary popoverBtn" (click)="toggleAddToListModalPopover(customPopover, $event)">Add to list</button>
```

example.component.ts:

```
protected toggleAddToListModalPopover(customPopover, e):void {
    customPopover.hide();
    this.showAddToListModal = !this.showAddToListModal;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```